# Trying to move entire rows based off data

Tags: excel, vba

So my code works but it looking for Codes AE, A, AA and AAA. When the code for the A runs it grabs all of them because they all start with A. How can I fix this ?

```
Dim rw1 As Long, lastrow1 As Long, MySel1 As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet

With Workbooks("11 Production").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rw1 = 1000 To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw1, 2).Value Like "*Minor Novice*" And .Cells(rw1, 3).Value Like ("*A*") Then
            If MySel1 Is Nothing Then
                Set MySel1 = .Cells(rw1, 1).EntireRow

                Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\CODE\Team Lists\11 Minor Novice A.xlsx"

            Else
                Set MySel1 = Union(MySel1, .Cells(rw1, 1).EntireRow)

            End If
        End If
    Next rw1
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice A")
    lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not MySel1 Is Nothing Then
        MySel1.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 1)
        'MySel.Delete
    End If
End With

Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice A").Range("A1:AY300")
Rng1.Copy
Dim s111 As Workbook
Set s111 = Workbooks("11 Minor Novice A.xlsx")
Dim last1 As Long
Dim Rngnew1 As Range

With s111.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        last1 = .Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Else
        last1 = 1
    End If
End With
Set Rngnew1 = s111.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & last)

Rngnew1.PasteSpecial
```

Expect to have every row with Minor Novice and A moved to its own sheet but since all the data in column C starts with an A it puts AE,A,AA and AAA onto the A workbook. Just need to know how to set an exact value instead of using "Like".

Comment: change `.Cells(rw1, 3).Value Like ("*A*")` into `.Cells(rw1, 3).Value = "A"`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ With an If else statement in VBA how do you tell it to just move on if the data youre looking fro isnt on the sheet?

Comment: don't get it. You must be much more precise when asking questions and you must give an example. Please read [mcve] and ask a proper question in the question part. Comments are not meant to ask questions.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ So for example: when there is cells with Minor Novice and A it will move them  to  a new book but if there is no Minor Novice A then i get a subscript error. I need my code to basically say if it doesnt exist then just move on

Comment: which error message do you get exactly and in which line?